# What's the best way to cache downloads done by docker while building containers?

Tags: docker, caching

While testing new Docker builds (modifying Dockerfile) it can take quite some time for the image to rebuild due to huge download size (either direct by wget, or indirect using apt, pip, etc)

One way around this that I personally use often is to just split commands I plan to modify into their own RUN variable. This avoids re-downloading some parts because previous layers are cached. This, however, doesn't cut it if the command that requires "tuning" is early on in the Dockerfile.

Another solution is to use an image that already contains most of the required packages so that it would just be pulled once and cached, but this can come with unnecessary "baggage".

**So is there a straight forward way to cache all downloads done by Docker while building/running?** I'm thinking of having Memcached on the host machine but it seems kind of an overkill. Any suggestions?

I'm also aware that I can test in an interactive shell first but sometimes you need to test the Dockerfile and make sure it's production-ready (including arguments and defaults) especially if the only way you will ever see what's going on after that point is ELK or cluster crash logs

Comment: You might need kind of multi-stage build in dockerfile -->https://medium.com/@baykara/optimize-docker-image-via-multi-stage-builds-dd8e8ec796de

Comment: I guess I am not understanding here, Docker will realize based on seeing the same instructions that nothing has changed from the last time you ran `docker build`. Docker already generates images out of previous steps applied. It has already generated an image out of that step and this image has been cached and stored on your local machine. So rather than going through the process of creating another container out of that image and running commands inside that container a second time, it says you know what I have already done this work, I will use the image that I generated previously.

Comment: So any new instructions, just place it at the end of the Dockerfile so it uses cache until it gets to your new instruction.

Comment: @full_steak_developer It's the same issue as layers if the change happens on an early stage.

Comment: @Daniel The scenario I'm referring to is when you are making multiple changes to a really big Docker file and it invalidates the cached layers/stages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here:
https://superuser.com/questions/303621/cache-for-apt-packages-in-local-network

Is the same question but regarding a local network instead of the same machine. However, the answer can be used in this scenario, it's actually a simpler scenario than a network with multiple machines.

If you [install Squid](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-squid-proxy-server-installation-configuration/) locally you can use it to cache all your downloads including your host-side downloads.

But more specifically, **there's also a [Squid Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/sameersbn/squid/) image!**

Headsup: If you use a squid service in a docker-compose file, don't forget to use the squid service name instead of docker's subnet gateway `172.17.0.1:3128` becomes `squid:3128`

Answer (score 0):

the way i did this was

- used the new `--mount=type=cache,target=/home_folder/.cache/curl`
- wrote a script which looks into the cache before calling curl (wrapper over curl with cache)
- called the script in the Dockerfile during build
- it is more a hack, works